# jQuery element.closest(...).attr is not a function when using each

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

When iterating over some DOM elements I found it impossible to use .data or .attr on them:

```
$('.running').each (index, element) =>
    console.log element.closest('[data-id]')
```

gets me

```
<section class="job-block" data-id="240"></section>
...
```

but

```
$('.running').each (index, element) =>
    console.log element.closest('[data-id]').data('id')
```

throws

> Uncaught TypeError: element.closest(...).data is not a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method that you are using is native JS method and which returns DOM element object since `element` refers DOM element object.

---

There are several options to get the attribute value, either get from [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property :

```
$('.running').each (index, element) =>
    console.log element.closest('[data-id]').dataset.id
```

---

Or wrap element by jQuery and use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
$('.running').each (index, element) =>
    console.log $(element.closest('[data-id]')).data('id')
```

---

Or wrap the `element` by jQuery and use jQuery [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

```
$('.running').each (index, element) =>
    console.log $(element).closest('[data-id]').data('id')
```

Comment: thanks!! It totally makes sense. Which one would be the fastest performing method on multiple elements in this case?

Comment: @Denis :  I think the fist one but it's(closest in JS) not widely supported.. So I would prefer the last one

Comment: I recommend always using the variant that sticks with a single tech, in this case the last one as all calls are jquery.  This helps remove any confusion whether you have a DOM element or jquery object and so improves maintainability.

Comment: In this case you probably don't want to use the js `closest`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 4):

Because they are DOM objects (as you rightly state) and not jquery objects, you can't apply jquery methods to DOM objects, you need to convert them to jquery objects.

```
$(element).closest...
```

Answer (score 3):

The `element` contains a DOMElement, so you're calling the [native closest() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), not the [jQuery one](http://api.jquery.com/closest). Hence the `data()` method does not exist on the returned object.

To fix this, wrap `element` in a jQuery object:

```
$('.running').each (index, element) =>
    console.log $(element).closest('[data-id]').data('id')
```

Answer (score 2):

`data()` is a jQuery method so you should call it on jQuery object instead of a DOM oject, so it should be `$(element)` :

```
console.log $(element).closest('[data-id]').data('id')
```

Hope this helps.